# Is there a simple way to do array differences and approximate array derivatives in C++? (Like the diff() function in matlab)

Tags: c++, diff, derivative

Matlab code I would like to translate into C++

```
X = [1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21]; 
Y = diff(X)
```

output : `0     1     1     2     3     5     8`

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html

Comment: the simple way is to write a loop.

Comment: My GoogleFu says there is at least one method: [c++ derivatives array](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+array+derivative&oq=c%2B%2B+array+derivative&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.9040j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ calls it [`std::adjacent_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference).

```
int X[8] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21}; 
int Y[8];

std::adjacent_difference( std::begin(X), std::end(X), std::begin(Y) );
```

Note that the first element of the destination is a direct copy of the source.  The remaining elements are differences.

[See it work on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jbKo9qee7).

Comment: Note: OP can get the exact sequence they want using `Y+1`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

void diff(int params[], int length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        std::cout << params[i + 1] - params[i] << " ";
    }
}
int main() {
    int x[] = { 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21 };
    int length =std::size(x); 
    diff(x, length);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to C++20 there is no standard algorithm that resembles Matlabs `diff` directly, but you can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


std::vector<int> diff(const std::vector<int>& x) {    
    if (x.size()==0) return {};
    std::vector<int> result(x.size()-1);
    std::transform(x.begin()+1,x.end(),x.begin(),result.begin(),std::minus<int>{});
    return result;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> x{1,3,4,5,6,10};
    auto d = diff(x);
    for (const auto& e : d) std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

`std::minus<int>{}` is a function object that returns the difference between its parameters. It is used as binary operator with `std::transform` to calculate the elementwise difference between `x` excluding the first element and `x` excluding the last element (for the second input range only the start of the range is passed to `std::transform`).

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hssKeYWE4)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69105108/4117728) for the algorithm you can use in C++20.

Answer (score 0):

Very naive implementation:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> diff(const std::vector<T>& array){
    std::vector<T> result;
    for(int i = 1; i < array.size(); ++i){
        result.push_back(array[i] - array[i-1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Note:* you can also add constraints on type T, feel free to consult C++ documentation.